# Manhwa where the female lead is reincarnated in a fantasy world and ends up in a haunted palace

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation, webcomics

I read this manwha months ago. It was about a female lead who got reincarnated in a fantasy world. Then somehow ended up moving to a palace. The female lead remembers that she reincarnated in a comedy genre novel but she noticed some strange things in the palace like it was haunted.

The title hinted that it changed from comedy to horror genre.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Might you be thinking of *[Silent Lady](https://forum.novelupdates.com/threads/secret-lady.125833/)*?

[image: Cover page of Silent Lady*]

> A child who has the ability to see ghosts, Yoon Seol-woo.
> Has reincarnated into Rosantine, a princess who could see ghosts.

It has a protagonist in a fantasy world who reincarnated into a person in a palace which is haunted, and the title is a bit creepy in its implications. Not matching, I haven't found any reference to the protagonist being aware that she's in a novel.